# Save as a web page - lists are not saved allways with UL or OL html tag

Tags: microsoft-word, html, microsoft-word-2013, save-as

I am getting documents created by other people that contain lists like this:

> - List item 1
> - List item 2

I need to convert them to HTML and I use Save as web page in Word. 
There is a problem that some lists are converted to `<ul><li>` tags but some are converted to

```
· List Item 1 
· List Item 2
```

with this `·` strange dot character and no `<ul>` tag.

```
<p class=MsoListParagraphCxSpMiddle style='text-indent:-18.0pt'><span
style='font-family:Symbol'>·<span style='font:7.0pt "Times New Roman"'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span></span><span style='font-family:"Times New Roman","serif"'>56464</span></p>
```

[Link to a sample document that produces this behavior](http://www.filedropper.com/sampledoc).

The only relevant difference between the two lists that I can see is that the second (problematic) list **has another style set** in the styles dialog on the ribbon bar.

The first has `Normal` style and the second has `Paragraph with a list` style. I am unable in Word 2013 to create the list with `Normal` style - do not know, how it was created.

Is there a trick how to fix this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like You have a different formatting styles in the doc.

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00BD738A" w:rsidRPr="00BD738A" w:rsidRDefault="00BD738A" w:rsidP="00CE27F3">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
            <w:numId w:val="1"/>
        </w:numPr>
        <w:jc w:val="both"/>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="20"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>ssssss</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
</w:p>
```

=========

```
<w:p w:rsidR="00BD738A" w:rsidRDefault="00BD738A" w:rsidP="00BD738A">
    <w:pPr>
        <w:pStyle w:val="Odstavecseseznamem"/>
        <w:numPr>
            <w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
            <w:numId w:val="3"/>
        </w:numPr>
        <w:jc w:val="both"/>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
        </w:rPr>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Times New Roman" w:hAnsi="Times New Roman"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t>rrrrr</w:t>
    </w:r>
    <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/>
</w:p>
```

You can see the difference between these two XML blocks.

What i did was, changed the document extension **.docx** to **.zip** and extracted it.

In side the extracted folder there is a folder called **word**.

There is an XML file called **document.xml** contains your document body contents.

**Solution:**
I selected the first part in the word document.

```
XXX:  
•   Aaaa
•   ssssss
•   xxxxxxx
```

and used the format painter tool to format the sescond part.

```
Nabízíme: 
•   rrrrr
•   asas klůsddlůask asdkllůasdklůasdklů asdlkasdlůkasdlůkadlůk asdlkasdlůasdklůasdklů  asdlkasdlůkasdlůkasdlůkasdk
•   asasasas
•   5 45464564
•   56464
•   87989789
```

and then saved it as HTML. The problem was solved.

You can try this if it is convenient for you.

Comment: Thank you, I have seen the differences in xml, but editing rendered the docx unopenable. The trick with the format painter works well, still I am curious what is behind, so shall wait a little before accepting this.